# KeyPress events for X windows

Tags: unix, x11

I'm trying to write a little app to capture keystrokes for a window under X and then display them onto the screen using OSD or something. The idea is to use it for screencasts and stuff like that.

I tried some surgery on [xev](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xev.1.html) and got it to work fine but then noticed something funny. If I use xev on the window which itself creates, the KEyPress and KeyRelease events are registered and I can see them. However, if I use the `-id` switch for xev to monitor another window and try to log keystrokes there, they KeyPress and KeyRelease events are not always displayed. I seem to get `PropertyNotify` events when some things happen but not `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` which are what I'm interested in.

Some windows behave as expected (e.g. gnome-terminal). Some others don't (e.g. emacs-gtk).

How do I get the keystrokes for these windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key events go to the window that has focus, which is not always the window that appears to have focus. When I try to use `xev` on my firefox window, key events go to one of its unviewable children (relative upper-left at (-1,-1), size (1,1).

You can use `XGetInputFocus()` to find out which window has focus.

Comment: Interesting. When I give focus to my Emacs window using `Alt-Tab`, it seems to receive the events and I can track them. When I do so by hovering my mouse over it, it doesn't. This is weird. How do I *give* focus to a window?

Comment: I guess that would be `XSetInputFocus`.

Comment: Programmatically, with`XSetInputFocus`.

Comment: This solves my problem (although I'm not sure of all the technical details) so I'm marking it as "Accepted". Thanks n.m.! :)